# cores da linha de interação em uma network

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-color, redes

Eu gostaria de elaborar um gráfico do tipo network (rede). Neste gráfico gostaria que as cores das linhas de interação (`col.interaction`) sejam da mesma cor da caixas superiores (`col.high`).

Alguém poderia me dizer o que eu preciso escrever no comando `col.interaction` para ter essa combinação de cores? Eu tentei coisas do tipo `col.interaction = col.high`, mas não deu certo.

Estou anexando uma imagem que se parece com a que quero.

Eu tentei:

```js
library("bipartite")
library("iNEXT")
library("vegan")
library("ggplot2")
dados<-t(dados)
plotweb(dados, arrow="down.center", method="normal", 
        text.rot=90, high.lablength=50, low.lablength=70,
        col.high = c("#66CC00", "#80FF00", "#80FF00", "#FF8000", "#66CC00","#FFFF00", "#66CC00", "#66CC00","#FFB266", "#FF0000"),
        col.low = "#994C00", bor.col.low= "#404040", bor.col.high= c("#66CC00", "#80FF00","#80FF00", "#FF8000", "#66CC00","#FFFF00", "#66CC00", "#66CC00", "#FFB266", "#FF0000"), 
col.interaction= col.high, bor.col.interaction =  col.high, y.lim=c(-0.26,6), low.y=0.69, high.y=3.7)
```

```html
coluna_sup A B C D
Aa 0 2 3 0
Bb  0 2 3 0
Cc  0 4 0 0
Dd  0 8 0 0
Ee 16 2 0 4
Ff 16 0 0 3
Gg 16 1 0 29
Hh 16 30 10 45
Jj 16 3 0 1
Ll 0 20 0 10
```

exemplo de imagem pretendida
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fran Braga, seu exemplo não está totalmente reproduzível, e isto dificulta um pouco. Sugiro 02 coisas para vc editar. 1- Apresente seus dados completamente através do `dput(dados)`; 2- Forneça um exemplo do plot que você sabe fazer e indique na imagem, se possível com setas ou alguma outra indicação, quais as modificações que você está tendo dificuldades em realizar.